# If statement is not working with my swing application

Tags: java, swing, if-statement

I am a java beginner, i wrote this application using netbeans. Its purpose is to get the entered value from the textbox and display it in a message box when i press the button. It works fine when i give the value in the textbox. When i press the button with out giving a value it is suppose to display nothing, but it displays an empty message box. So please help me to fix the problem.

```
private void ChecktheloopActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                             
       String recno= numsearch1.getText();   
       String srname=searchname.getText();
       if(recno!=null){
       JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,recno);
   }
}
```

Comment: If I recall correctly, since, I think 1.4, getText is guaranteed to return a non null value

Answer (score 1):

try it

```
private void ChecktheloopActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                             
           String recno= numsearch1.getText();   
           String srname=searchname.getText();
           if(recno!=null && recno.trim().length()>0){
           JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,recno);
       }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You also have to check if the string is equals to `""` before showing the dialog box.

```
private void ChecktheloopActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                             
    String recno= numsearch1.getText();   
    String srname=searchname.getText();
    if(!recno.equals("")){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,recno);
    }
}
```

`numsearch1.getText();` is probably returning an empty string instead of the `null` you were expecting.

Answer (score 0):

You have to check if text is an empty string, using `isEmpty()` method of String class:

```
private void ChecktheloopActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                             
           String recno= numsearch1.getText();   
           String srname=searchname.getText();
           if(!recno.isEmpty()){
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,recno);
           }
      }
```